# Using Tridion Sites 9.6 Core Service.REST API saving component

Tags: core-service, component, sites-9.6, rest, json

While I am going through Tridion Sites 9.6 Core Service.REST API for saving an item it is mentioned as follows

```
"/v{api-version}/items": {
  "post": {
    "tags": [
      "Item"
    ],
    "summary": "Creates an object based on a specified request model and saves it to the database. For versioned items, a check-in is performed by default.",
    "description": "This operation returns an instance of 'IdentifiableObject' type, as implemented by one of the following:<ul class=\"model-list\"><li><span>ApprovalStatus</span></li><li><span>Bundle</span></li><li><span>BusinessProcessType</span></li><li><span>Category</span></li><li><span>Component</span></li><li><span>ComponentTemplate</span></li><li><span>Folder</span></li><li><span>Group</span></li><li><span>Keyword</span></li><li><span>MultimediaType</span></li><li><span>Page</span></li><li><span>PageTemplate</span></li><li><span>Publication</span></li><li><span>Schema</span></li><li><span>SearchFolder</span></li><li><span>StructureGroup</span></li><li><span>TargetGroup</span></li><li><span>TargetType</span></li><li><span>TemplateBuildingBlock</span></li><li><span>TridionProcessDefinition</span></li><li><span>User</span></li></ul>\n\n",
    "operationId": "Create",
    "consumes": [
      "application/json"
    ],
    "produces": [
      "application/json"
    ],
```

Does it mean we can pass formatted json (earlier we used to create a formatted xml and pass to component.content or component.Metdata) and create component programmatically?
Note: we are yet to migrate to 9.6.

Comment: What do you mean by 'formatted json'?

Comment: Tridion 9.5 expects XML in specific format, similar way in newer version will Tridion can consume predefined json format

Comment: still, the Core Tridion component source is still stored as XML only, but Core Service.REST API expects in JSON format and then backend it will convert to store in XML to Tridion database.

Comment: Hi Velu, Thank you, This is the what I am looking, Can you please update as Answer, I will accept it, one small clarification, Can we install "Core Service.REST API" alone without upgrading to 9.6 as it backward compatible